# How to create dynamic multi steps side bar menu in angular 7?

Tags: angular7

I am using angular 7 version. I am create a dynamic multi steps side bar menu. But problem is If any menu is open, then open seconds any menu of the list so already open menu is closed. Please tell me how I am implement is. I am share a code:- [dynamic-nested-sidenav-menu](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-sidenav-menu?file=app%2Fmenu-list-item%2Fmenu-list-item.component.html)